# NoClassFoundException for javafx.application.Application after run JavaFX Maven Plugin (fix-classpath)

Tags: java, swing, maven, javafx

I am working on JavaFX/Swing project.

When I did run it or debug it from Netbeans, it worked fine.

But trying to integrate it with launch4j, I ran the `mvn com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:fix-classpath` command explained on [JavaFX Maven Plugin](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/fix-classpath.html) page, and since that it throws **NoClassFoundException** every time I try to run or debug from Netbeans.

By other hand, when I build the project and executed from jar or executable file generated by launch4j, it work fine.

How can I able to run or debug project from Netbeans again?

Thanks on advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java 8+/NetBeans 8+, that places JavaFX on the standard Java classpath, and you won't have to deal with `NoClassFoundExceptions` for JavaFX classes.